# Azure push notification not working after api hosted on azure

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am developing an REST Web API in .net and using Azure push notification - targeting apple devices first. Everything is working fine, api and push notification in my dev box. Api can send push notification to apple devices (iPhone).

When I deployed web api on azure(as web site) api seems to be not sending push notification(Yes devices are successfully registering to notification hub). I have check all possible way & configuration that I could think of but no luck. What could be the reason why azure notification is not working after hosted the the api on azure. Or what obvious thing I might be missing :(

Here is my [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912711/azure-notification-hub-tags-not-creating-not-updating-to-target-specific-user/)

Thanks,

Comment: Solved now. I needed to set certificate for PROD. If you try to use sandbox certificate in hosted site Notification hub cleans up registrations. Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190777/azure-notification-hub-registrations-disappear-when-sending-a-notification)